# Linq Parent Child Query to SQL Server

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I would like to do a querying to table with Parent Child Table Relationship as follow

tblCampaignComment (Parent) 
tblCampaignCommentLike (Child)

I have come out with both method to return result as follow, but to me seems both method are not PERFORMANCE optimise. I will need to either take the performance hit on database or on the application.

**Method A** -> I need to perform multiple queries in database (for each comment) 
**Method B** -> I need to perform foreach loop to filter, query and append. More code needed (it gonna be bad if i have a lot of child data to be process)

I wonder if there is a better one size fit all method that I am unaware of.
If not, which of method A and method B is more preferable?

**Method A (Select Child from Database)**

```
var commentWithLikesList = entities.tblCampaignComment
    .Where(x => x.CampaignId == campaign_id)
    .Select(o => new CampaignCommentWithLikes
    {
        CampaignId = o.CampaignId,
        CommentId = o.CommentId,
        CommentLikes = entities.tblCampaignCommentLike.Where(x => x.CommentId == o.CommentId).ToList()
    }
    )
    .OrderBy(x => x.CampaignCommentCreatedDt)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(input.PageSize).ToList();
```

**Method B (Group Join follow by for loop filtering)**

```
var comments = entities.tblCampaignComment
    .Where(x => x.CampaignId == campaign_id)
    .OrderBy(x => x.CampaignCommentCreatedDt)
    .Skip(skip)
    .Take(input.PageSize)
    .GroupJoin(
        entities.tblCampaignCommentLike,
        cc => cc.CampaignId,
        ccl => ccl.CampaignId,
        (cc, ccl) => new
        {
            CampaignComment = cc,
            CampaignCommentLike = ccl
        }
    )
    .ToList();

var commentWithLikesList = new List<CampaignCommentWithLikes>();
foreach (var comment in comments)
{
    var commentWithLikes = new CampaignCommentWithLikes();
    commentWithLikes.CampaignId = comment.CampaignComment.CommentId;
    commentWithLikes.CommentId = comment.CampaignComment.CommentId;
    commentWithLikes.CommentLikes = new List<tblCampaignCommentLike>();

    if (comment.CampaignCommentLike != null)
    {
        foreach (var commentLike in comment.CampaignCommentLike)
        {
            if (commentLike.CommentId == commentWithLikes.CommentId)
            {
                commentWithLikes.CommentLikes.Add(commentLike);
            }
        }
    }

        commentWithLikesList.Add(commentWithLikes);
}
```

**The outcome result should be as follow:**

```
[
  {
    CampaignId: "1",
    CommentId: "1",
    ...
    ...
    CommentLikes: [
      {
    UserId: "1",
        UserName: "T",
      },
      {
        UserId: "1",
        UserName: "L",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    CampaignId: "2",
    CommentId: "2",
    ...
    ...
    CommentLikes: [

    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Do you have Cartesian Explosion with method **MethodA**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using entity framework you can eagerly load entities with an `Include` call.

Something like the following

```cs
entities.tblCampaignComment
        .Include(x => x.CampaignCommentLike) //This is the new line from the code in your question
        .Where(x => x.CampaignId == campaign_id)
        .OrderBy(x => x.CampaignCommentCreatedDt)
        .Skip(skip)
        .Take(input.PageSize)
```

This requires that `CampaignCommentLike` be a navigation property on `tblCampaignComment` but will let the database do an inner join between the two tables and EF will handle the parent child one to many relationship.

Comment: This essentially produce the same result as groupjoin right? at the end of the day i still need to use foreach loop to group data and push it to CampaignLikes am i right (refer Method B end part foreach) and `outcome` section that I wanted? wouldn't that take performance hit if i have a lot of campaignlike data to filter

Comment: I am not talking about db querying performance now. Rather using for each loop to group and append data to the desired output after the result is retrieve. Or this is something inevitable? If let say for each campaign comment like i have 1000 or more rows to loop through processing after each has been retrieve woudn't that that a performance hits as it is O(n) operation

Comment: @eulercode the great thing about Include and navigation properties in Entity Framework is that the library automagically populates the object you are looking to get out.  Somewhere there will be a loop of some sort to map the one to many normalized tables to the object model.  Microsoft has lots of really smart people who spend lots of time optimizing the EF code.  It’s very similar to option A but the EF library code handles the mapping instead of you as a developer writing code for the eager loading.